# Cannot Remove Polyine in googlemap fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, maps

This is for making polyline

```
for (int j = 0; j < user.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject routes = user.getJSONObject(j);
                        JSONArray rute = routes.getJSONArray("points");

                        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
                        for (int k = 0; k < rute.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject users = rute.getJSONObject(k);
                            double rutes = users.getDouble("latitude");
                            double rutess = users.getDouble("longitude");
                            options.color(Color.parseColor("#FFA866"));
                            options.width(10);
                            options.geodesic(true);
                            options.add(new LatLng(rutes, rutess));

                            Log.d("TAG", "Hasil latitude = " + rutes);
                            Log.d("TAG", "Hasil longtitude = " + rutess);
                            jumlah_klik = jumlah_klik + 1;
                        }
                        polyline_bis = mMap.addPolyline(options);
                    }
```

This is for remove polyline

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if (polyline_bis != null){
                    polyline_bis.remove();
                }else {
                    Log.d("TAG","not removee");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

this is initialize map fragment

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(SearchDanBisKlik.this);
        Places.initialize(SearchDanBisKlik.this, getString(R.string.api_key));
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
```

this is on GoogleMap googleMap initialize

```
mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

The question is:
I cannot remove polyline when i click the marker, how can i remove that? help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Polylines added several (`user.length()`) times, but reference to polyline stored into same variable `polyline_bis`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < user.length(); j++) {
    ...
    polyline_bis = mMap.addPolyline(options);
}
```

In that case `polyline_bis` handles reference only to last added polyline object.
Probably you need to store added polylines into `List` and each time when marker clicked select appropriate object for marker.

Comment: @Noerrachmat- Please add more code e.g. where `polyline_bis` declared, marker created etc.